# PHP Looping through months for blog archive

Tags: php, date, loops

I'm trying to create a list of the years with the months from today until the oldest record in the database.
It's working great, except that the loop stops before it gets to the oldest month.  Here's my code:

```
echo $oldest_entry; //2012-01-31
$end = strtotime($oldest_entry);
$month = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
$year = "";
while($month >= $end)
{
     if(date('Y', $month) != $year){ 
        echo "<b>".date('Y', $month)."</b><br/>";
        $year = date('Y', $month); 
     }
     echo date('F', $month)."<br/>";
     $month = strtotime("-1 month", $month);
}
```

It outputs:
**2012**

March

February

And doesn't get to January.  What am I doing wrong here?  I thought adding the = to the > would fix this but it didn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't print January because `2012-01-16 >= 2012-01-31` is false.

You should omit the date. Use only the year and the month in your comparison.